# The effect of freezing on beer taste

Tags: taste

Beer (with the exception of mulled beer) tastes best when cooled. But sometimes there can be too much cooling, for example when you take beer with you on hiking to enjoy the taste at the camping. The beer can freeze (the glass bottle would explode, but the plastic ones are more resistant).

How such freezing and melting impact the beer taste?

Comment: See this answer from the Home Brewing stack exchange: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/what-happens-when-beer-freezes

Answer (score 2):

From my own experience the effect of frozen-thawed beer tends to be flatter and have a more watery consistency.

Possibly this similar question on HomeBrew could help you: [Link to HomeBrew question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/what-happens-when-beer-freezes)

Answer (score 1):

Use it as an opportunity to try making [ice beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_beer).

> Ice beer was developed by brewing a strong, dark lager, then freezing the beer and removing some of the ice. This concentrates the aroma and taste of the beer, and also raises the alcoholic strength of the finished beer. This produces a beer with 12 to 15 per cent alcohol. In North America, water would be added to lower the alcohol level.

Basically it can improve the flavour - I have tried "proper" ice beer and it's good!

I've heard of a method where they essentially defrost it upside down over a container and you drink what melts (since ethanol melts at lower temps than water).

For obvious reasons (i.e. you're unsealing the container), the beer won't be as fizzy.